# Why is the energy emitted by a black body low at higher frequencies?

Tags: energy, thermal-radiation, frequency

In the blackbody radiation spectrum, we clearly see that energy radiated is very less at higher frequencies.

> "At high frequencies the amount of energy in a quantum, $hf$, is so large that the high-frequency vibrations can never get going! This is why the blackbody spectrum always becomes small at the left-hand (high frequency) side."

Here's a statement I came across in the following webpage https://physics.weber.edu/carroll/honors/failures.htm

I can't quite understand it

Comment: The answer is somehow related to quantum mechanics. The classical prediction lead to a [ultraviolet catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe) (where high frequencies contributed more and more).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is contained in the Planck Law.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law

Answer (score 0):

The [black body radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) is one of the main  strong  disagreements with measurements and classical expectations that led to the development of quantum mechanics. (the [photoelectric effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html) and the s[pectra of atoms](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect.html) were also in strong disagreements with classical electrodynamics)

[image: black body]

The Planck formula solves the ultraviolet catastropy , many high energy photon, that the classical hypothesis had. Both the classical and the Planck formulas come from considering electromagnetic waves in a cavity, as you can read in the link. The classically derived formula had a great increase in the number of modes at high frequencies, but the data did not show this.

> A mode for an electromagnetic wave in a cavity must satisfy the condition of zero electric field at the wall. If the mode is of shorter wavelength, there are more ways you can fit it into the cavity to meet that condition. Careful analysis by Rayleigh and Jeans showed that the number of modes was proportional to the frequency squared.

[image: classical cavity mode]

> From the assumption that the electromagnetic modes in a cavity were quantized in energy with the quantum energy equal to Planck's constant times the frequency, Planck derived a radiation formula. **The average energy per "mode" or "quantum" is the energy of the quantum times the probability that it will be occupied** (the Einstein-Bose distribution function):

bold mine

[image: planck formula]

and the formula fitted the data.

In the formula the probability of having a mode with very high energy, i.e. large photon energy( h*ν) goes to zero for high frequency (ν)  .

The derivation of the formula is within a cavity defined both for the classical and the quantum study. In the classical there is no bound on the cavities walls on the frequency, it could fall on the wall in any part of the classical wave shape. Imposing quantization reduces the possible waves that can interact with the walls .

Note the probability part in the above quote. The black body distribution depends on the probability of having high frequencies in the cavity.
The quantization demand drastically reduced the infinity of high frequencies that the Rayleigh-Jeans law gave, to zero for high frequencies.